# How can I catch and handle pressing and long pressing of a call key in activity Android API 19?

Tags: android

How can I catch pressing and long pressing a key in activity (keyCode=5)?
I tried to use the `onKeydown` and `onkeyLongPress` methods, but it does not work for me. It works only when I press the up call key. I catch it using the `onKeyup` method of activity. I also tried to catch the long pressing of digits, but it also doesn't work for me.

Help me please: How could I solve my problem?
Thanks everybody for the help.

This is my code so far:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
  if(event.getRepeatCount()==0) 
    event.startTracking();
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
  Toast.makeText(
    this.getApplicationContext(),keyCode+"",0
  ).show();
  return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
}
```